# Turn a vector by an angle

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need a simple way to turn a vector by an angle. I know that it works with rotation matrix but i dont know how to use it. Can u give me a simple formular?

Comment: All the formulas you need are here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix. If you don't understand what's written there, you'll profit more from asking a specific question about what you don't understand than from asking in this generality.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix I think it explains a lot, if you work on Cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the links above, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) is how to perform matrix multiplication. Please keep us updated of your progress and any questions that you get after you have attempted the problem.

Also, please add the [homework] tag to all homework questions.

Comment: @Theo: I try to put in as much effort into my answers as the OP puts into the question, except that I round up to grammatical correctness if necessary. Do you think I should delete and comment out?